# React-native / Expo: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference message error

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, axios

I'm trying to get my MongoDB database linked to my front react-native app, and I can't get rid of this error message when I run the app with Expo: "*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference*".

I think my error occurs in the 'then function' right after my axios request:

```
getConnected = () => {
console.log('still ok');
axios.get(`api/signin/${this.state.email}/${this.state.password}`)
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log('Fetching data');
  }.bind(this))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.res);
  });
```

}

I've created a proxy in the package.json in order to link the database to the app, I'm not sure this is the right way to do it. I'm a beginner!

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Let me know if you need further details.
Thanks!

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyxWw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had this problem a minute ago. It seems if the URL is invalid, you will get this error.

For my folder set up I had something like app.js and a folder called api, with a file called api.json. You cannot fetch the folder from here like you would with a html application. For example

```
fetch("./api/api.json")
```

The above would return the error you are getting.
You need to use the Assets system.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/assets

Comment: Thanks Armando. I'm not sure I understand though. How can I know that my url is invalid? In a router.js file, this url has been setted up: 
"router.route('/signin/:email/:password').get(Authentification.signin);". I've tried with and without api before "/signin..." and it doesn't change anything. As for assets, it's quite confusing for me. Do I need to apply it on my axios requests?

Comment: Ok, I've finally find out that my url wasn't good, indeed. I managed to get into my ajax request. Now I'll try to get something else than an undefined response. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks, please select my answer as the accepted answer

Comment: It seems like you are trying to host your backend files inside your react application. That will not work